# remove a div from returned function(data)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am running a jQuery `$.post` function that returns data from a php page.  In that page some divs with specific ids get created.  What I need to do is delete a div if it's already found on the current web page, but let the others go through.  Here's the code:

```
var phpDivs = [];
$(data).filter("div").each(function(){ phpDivs.push(this.id); });
var pageDivs = [];
$("#items").find("div").each(function() { pageDivs.push(this.id); });
                
$.each(phpDivs, function(indexphp, phpDiv) {
    $.each(pageDivs, function(indexpage, pageDiv) {
        if (pageDiv == phpDiv) {
            alert("match");
            $(phpDiv, $(data)).delete(); //problem code
        }
    });
});

$(data).appendTo("#items").show("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
```

The commented line above appears to delete all divs, instead of just a specific div.  I've also tried:

```
$('"#'+ phpDiv + '"', $(data)).delete();
```

with the same result.

---

#### Edit

Came across something interesting.  If I replace the problem code with this:

```
data = $(data).html("<p>blah</p>");
```

Then it will actually change the data object.  I cannot use `$(data)`.  However, I still can't get this to work the way I want with no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Is the code you posted resides inside success handler of the `load()` call? What is `data`? What is `#items`?

Comment: #items is a div that holds all the other divs on the page.  data is the returned echos from the php file.  I didn't explicitly call any load() function, but everything resides in the $(document).ready function.

Comment: `data` returns what I'm guessing is a string, but written in html format.  For example it's getting the information from a php page in the form: `echo "<div id='item4'>the item</div>";`  But there are several more elements within the div, not just text.

Answer (score 0):

try `$('"#'+ phpDiv + '"', $(data)).remove();`

Comment: this didn't work either.  Rather than delete the div, it allowed it onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

yep try this

```
$('"#'+ phpDiv + '"').remove();
```

That should remove the div you do not want

Answer (score -1):

Try [.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: remove gives me the same result.

Comment: In Chrome, if you use console.log($('"#'+ phpDiv + '"', $(data))) Does it output the correct divs?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the chrome console, but if I alert(phpDiv); yes it does give the correct div id.

Comment: That's good. Can you do anything else to those divs? Like changing the background color or something trivial?

Comment: I can't add CSS to the problem line.  But on the next line where I append everything to the page I can.